# Tag wiki edit suggestions without any changes

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

Edit suggestions can be make to Tag Wiki without no changes at all. Is this by-design that there is no character count limit similar to regular edit suggestions?

A recent example:

[image]

Comment: I've already reported this case on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/a-suggested-edit-was-submitted-without-any-changes