# What were the 3 characters added in this edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I rejected a tag wiki edit since it accomplished what [appeared to be literally nothing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5557). Though it said 3 characters were added.

First guess was spaces or something. I would have expected the change to show up in the markdown. Instead all we see is 10 identical lines skipped?

What could have been added? `<--` or something?

Comment: That's really weird.  Even the markdown shows no changes.  I guess the comment lied.  But an "empty" edit suggestion?

Comment: the "faq" was added, no?

Comment: I don't want to make tests just to see.

Comment: @Plutonix I suppose. Never seen an edit like that so I was not clear on that.

Comment: I would guess that the editor made the edit, then realized it was stupid and removed their edit, but for some reason that still needs to be approved though there is no longer a change from the original revision. I don't know if this is handled by SE or not, though.

Comment: It could be that the editor added "Hi " to the beginning, which was then automatically trimmed out, except that edit suggestions to the body have to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Doing a search on tag wiki edits, [I found out this has actually happened before.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254172/tag-wiki-edit-suggestions-without-any-changes) It was also [reported on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/a-suggested-edit-was-submitted-without-any-changes) with neither post receiving any sort of response from the team.

Comment: @Kendra It appears to be so.... and Shog9 is involved with both of them .... :)

Comment: @Kendra failed attempt at being cheeky is all it was

Comment: Maybe this is where we find out that there's some kind of auto-reject-edit on the content he generates. It's the way with authoritarian people to bend the system to reject passing control to others. ;)

Comment: Happened before, give it a more throughout check: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287760/totally-blank-edit-revision/287854#287854 At a wild guess, I'd say the user (accidentally) replaced \n newlines with \r\n or something like that...

Comment: @Mints97 It would seem you are right. Doesnt look like I will be able to verify it though. I wont be able to see  the source in the same way the answerer did in your linked post. Thanks though

Comment: But if this was a CRLF change, then why was the user able to submit a suggestion of <6 characters?  That still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Could it be that a URL has changed and the "identical lines" ignores URLs or BBCodes?

Comment: Perhaps someone could try "reproducing" the same edit?

Comment: I don't know what about \r\n, but in raw HTML I see that in current state of the text there's tight `<p>Your question` and in his proposed-and-rejected edit there's `<p> Your question` with space after <P>, and it's true for both paragraphs. That'd make 2 chars. I don't see the third. I have peeked that with F12/inspect in Chrome, so sorry if Chrome inspector cheated me on this one.

Comment: I just tried editing, and before each paragraph (good news, your questions, if you'd) I added a space, and such edit got accepted and put into review queue.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: that's not going to work unless Sandeep participated in the comments on this post already.

Comment: Is it not possible that the editor typed the comment himself?

Comment: @RegisteredUser: there should still be enough changes in the edit for them to be able to submit.