# Suggested tag-wiki edit - no changes at all

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I'm unable to spot the modification in the following tag wiki edit. Is it a bug?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14177537

Comment: It has happened before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254172/tag-wiki-edit-suggestions-without-any-changes

Comment: @S.L.Barth According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231328/338645, "This seems to be fixed." Unfortunately however, it's back now! ;)

Comment: Thank god the change was approved! we might never have seen the great improvement that it had to offer.

Comment: I wonder if it was a white space change that does not show up.

Comment: Console -> `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.diff-add')).map(function(e){return e.textContent})`. TL;DR: Seems like a trailing newline was added.

Comment: How the heck does that get 3 "approve" votes? Do reviewers actually read anything?

Comment: As a follow up, I posted a feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337529/2441442

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As Siguza mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337414/suggested-tag-wiki-edit-no-changes-at-all/337528#comment410367_337414), they added a newline - likely submitted accidentally along with https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40238731/2. I see no malice here on the part of the editor.

The reviewers, on the other hand, have been handled separately.

Comment: Maybe it should'n be possible to submit changes like that.